# Cumulative distribution function with integral

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a random variable on a probability space with measure $\mathbb{P}$. Then we can find the corresponding measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}$, which is $$\mu(B)=\mathbb{P}(X\in B)$$ where $B$ is a Lebesgue measurable set. Also we may define a cumulative distribution function $F:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow [0,1]$ by $F(x)=\mathbb{P}(X\le x)$.

It is not difficult to show that $\int_{\Omega}f(X(\omega))d\mathbb{P}(\omega)=\int_\mathbb{R}f(x)d\mu(x)$.
However, I saw a notation $\int_\mathbb{R}f(x)dF(x)$ instead of $\int_\mathbb{R}f(x)d\mu(x)$. Is there any mathmatical reason to justify the integral with culmulative distribution function? Or it is just a notation problem?

Comment: It's called a Lebesgue–Stieltjes integral:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integration

Comment: Jesus..thank you very much!!!